# Java Version Platform and Developer Version

Tags: java, api, version, platform

The Java Versions: 
“1.0.”,  “1.1”,  odd named “Java 2,"Java 2 version 1.2.”,  "Java 2 version 1.3”, “Java 2, version 1.4”,“Java 2, version 5.0., and so on and so on

MY question is are these the Developers versions or the Platform versions? And why did it leap from 1.4 to 5?

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the "leap" is Java 5's "real" internal version number was/is 1.5 (and Java 6 is 1.6 and so on). For whatever reason Sun decided (beginning with 1.5) to refer to it as 5 instead of 1.5 (but they mean the same thing). The most recent version is 1.7 but is referred to almost exclusively as Java 7. The specific version is 1.7.05 (version 7, update 5).

Prior to Java 5 the Enterprise Edition was referred to as Java 2 (and the 1.x versions were the Standard Edition), beginning with Java 5 the Enterprise Edition became known as Java Enterprise Edition - often shortened to Java EE (you may still see old references to J2EE though)